# jQuery UI Sortable for a whole div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have inside of a div image and text and I want to sort the whole div only by dragging the image and not the text.

```
<div id="sortable" class="row">
<div >
  <img id="sortable" src="images/arrow.png" style="cursor: move;"  /> 
  <strong>Item 1</strong> 
</div>
<div>
  <img id="sortable" src="images/arrow.png" style="cursor: move;"/> 
  <strong>Item 2</strong> 
 </div>
<div >
  <img id="sortable" src="images/arrow.png" style="cursor: move;"  /> 
  <strong>Item 3</strong> 
</div>
<div>
  <img id="sortable" src="images/arrow.png" style="cursor: move;"/> 
  <strong>Item 4</strong> 
</div>
</div>
```

jQuery :

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
cancel: ".fixed"
});
$("#sortable").disableSelection();
```

Demo :http://jsfiddle.net/kT4PV/4/

Comment: create a table with two columns. Make the img's draggable and then create a jQuery listener for event changes on the draggable objects.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You have multiple id's with the same name.

Comment: Change your `id`'s to `class`. Ids have to be unique, classes do not.

Answer (score 1):

The `fixed` class was never present in your fiddle:

### updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kT4PV/5/)

Answer (score 1):

in your example, add class fixed to strong

```
<strong class="fixed">Item 1</strong>
```